# YYYYMMDD format

Tags: r, date

```
structure(list(date = c(20140717L, 20140611L, 20140611L, 20140704L, 
20140411L, 20140906L, 20140512L, 20140717L, 20140819L, 20140415L, 
20140812L, 20140403L, 20140424L, 20140818L, 20140922L, 20140625L, 
20141006L, 20140918L, 20140811L, 20140819L, 20140602L, 20140626L, 
20140729L, 20140624L, 20140909L, 20140705L, 20140920L, 20140515L, 
20140531L, 20140628L, 20140822L, 20140508L, 20140809L, 20140627L, 
20140727L, 20140711L, 20140714L, 20140710L, 20140403L, 20140525L, 
20140428L, 20140501L, 20140915L, 20140510L, 20140601L, 20140921L, 
20140815L, 20140610L, 20140418L, 20140812L, 20140614L, 20140814L, 
20140626L, 20140412L, 20140912L, 20140514L, 20140919L, 20140706L, 
20140411L, 20140711L, 20140624L, 20140430L, 20140521L, 20140418L, 
20140713L, 20140424L, 20140601L, 20140923L, 20140406L, 20140905L, 
20140613L, 20140412L, 20140407L, 20140402L, 20140813L, 20140903L, 
20140827L, 20140521L, 20140524L, 20140404L, 20140419L, 20140412L, 
20140902L, 20140623L, 20140925L, 20140528L, 20140731L, 20140513L, 
20140821L, 20140703L, 20140724L, 20140818L, 20140801L, 20140628L, 
20140801L, 20140521L, 20140906L, 20140725L, 20140522L, 20140927L, 
20140615L, 20140920L, 20140813L, 20140815L, 20140924L, 20140614L, 
20140912L, 20140710L, 20140807L, 20140501L, 20140420L, 20140630L, 
20140704L, 20140401L, 20140605L, 20140928L, 20140806L, 20140614L, 
20140907L, 20140704L, 20140403L, 20140804L, 20140603L, 20140728L, 
20140919L, 20140731L, 20140426L, 20140930L, 20140502L, 20140827L, 
20140815L, 20140628L, 20140902L, 20140616L, 20140613L, 20140726L, 
20140721L, 20140425L, 20140715L, 20140607L, 20140913L, 20140621L, 
20140708L, 20140427L, 20140506L, 20140425L, 20140411L, 20140615L, 
20140713L, 20140424L, 20140406L, 20140711L, 20140415L, 20140909L, 
20141004L, 20140725L, 20140602L, 20140405L, 20140525L, 20140605L, 
20140521L, 20140506L, 20140414L, 20140916L, 20140512L, 20140830L, 
20140722L, 20140711L, 20140628L, 20140613L, 20140618L, 20140719L, 
20140416L, 20140727L, 20140521L, 20140718L, 20140814L, 20140515L, 
20140501L, 20140725L, 20140507L, 20140619L, 20140525L, 20140609L, 
20140614L, 20140402L, 20140914L, 20140517L, 20140826L, 20140602L, 
20140920L, 20140718L, 20140915L, 20140715L, 20140708L, 20140419L, 
20140819L, 20140501L, 20140807L, 20140404L)), .Names = "date", row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = "data.frame")
```

This data frame has date values as class of integer. This data set is just one column of my data set. The original data set also has another variable called "total sales". I want to make a plot which has dates in X axis and on Y axis, total sales.[image]

However, because the dates are regarded as integer, the plot is bad. So I want to let R understand the date column as date variables so I can get improved plot.

How can it be possible? Please give me help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you should consider adding the code you've used in order to create your plot, as this is not a part of your question. From there it should be a small modification.

Comment: You could use `df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%Y%m%d")` where `df` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have better luck with `as.Date`.  If `df` is the data, then you can do

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%Y%m%d")
with(df, plot(date))
```

[image]

Comment: Is the dollar key on your keyboard not working? Save yourself a load of keystrokes with `df$date` instead of `df[["date"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is the date column, you can try:

```
strptime(t(d),format='%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Or just `strptime(d, "%Y%m%d")` since `strptime` is vectorized.  But you'll have trouble plotting that since it returns `POSIXlt` lists

Comment: dates1 <- data.frame(sapply(dates1, function(x) strptime(x,format='%Y%m%d')))

I used this, but it has only NA values in each element.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. I forgot to transpose the column to a vector for `strptime` to work! Simplified version posted now.